# Como reusar informacion dentro de una biblioteca de clases .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, libreria

Estoy empezando con .NET 7 y tengo un proyecto.
Tenemos un CMS propio en la empresa, que genera sus datos en un XML, así que para hacer las webs en Razor, tengo una librería (con muchas clases en diferentes ficheros) que lee de esos XML y los convierte en clases.

La cuestión es que yo necesito configurar esa librería para que lea de donde debe y no lo quiero hacer cada vez que la necesite, sino una única vez al inicio de la aplicación.

He investigado sobre la inyección de dependencias y los singleton, pero me estoy liando un poco.

A la conclusión que he llegado es que usando DI dentro de la libreria no puedo acceder a la configuracion.

Imaginad que la librería tiene 3 clases: Artículo, Archivo y Apartado

Lo que quiero evitar es enviar la edición en cada constructor: `new Apartado(idApartado,idEdicion)`

y, sin embargo, llamar UNA ÚNICA VEZ a una clase nueva llamada configuracion: `new configuracion(idEdicion)`
y más adelante un `new Apartado(idApartado)`

y que esa clase configuración sea global a todas las clases de la librería

¿Se puede?
¿Es un completo sin sentido?

Comment: Explica lo de "necesito configurar esa librería para que lea de <donde debe>"

Comment: Esa libreria lee los XML de un directorio, en el que hay muchos subdirectorios(cada uno es una edicion). Necesito decirle de alguna manera el subdirectorio a leer

Comment: Imaginate un wordpress pero que en vez de gestionar un unico sitio, gestiona infinitos sitios. Esa configuracion se guarda en subdirectorios con el id de esa edicion

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero despejarte esa duda.

Lo que debes entender es que puedes tener varios constructores en una misma clase.

Supongamos lo siguiente clase:

```
class Test {
    int prop1;
    bool prop2;
    string prop3;

}
```

Si le agregas los siguientes constructores :

```
public Test(int ctr1Prop1)
{
    prop1 = ctr1Prop1;
}

public Test(bool ctr1Prop2)
{
    prop2 = ctr1Prop2;
}

public Test(string ctr1Prop3)
{
    prop3 = ctr1Prop3;
}

public Test(bool ctr1Prop2,string ctr1Prop3)
{
    prop2 = ctr1Prop2;
    prop3 = ctr1Prop3;
}
```

Como puedes observar tienes 3 constructores para cada propiedad. Eso quiere decir que dependiendo de tus necesidades puedes agregar o crear uno que necesites. Ahora ten en cuenta que cada constructor tiene vario por su tipo de dato.

Por lo tanto las siguientes instancias son correctas:

```
Test prueba1 = new Test(1);
Test prueba2 = new Test(false);
Test prueba3 = new Test("Datos de prueba3");
Test prueba4 = new Test(true, "Datos de prueba4");
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @DavElsanto. Ya lo sabia y ademas, no soluciona mi problema ya que el parametro siempre he de saberlo.Lo que yo quiero es que la libreria lo busque y pueda acceder a el, por medio de una preconfiguracion a la hora de arrancar la web

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he conseguido usando una mezcla de clases estaticas. Estoy investigando con DI a ver que saco.

Program.cs:

```
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
ClaseConfigurar.ConfigurarCMS(builder.Configuration);
....
```

ClaseConfigurar.cs:

```
   using ClassLibraryName;
    
    namespace AplicacionDepurar
    {
        public static class ClaseConfigurar
        {
            public static void ConfigurarCMS(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                ConfiguracionCMS.ClaveApartadoUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuracion:ClaveApartadoUrl");
                ....
            }
    
        }
    }
```

**EN LA BIBLIOTECA DE CLASES:**

ConfiguracionCMS.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibraryName
{
    public class ConfiguracionCMS
    {
        ....
        private static string _claveApartadoUrl;
        ....
        
        ....
        public static string ClaveApartadoUrl { get => _claveApartadoUrl; set => _claveApartadoUrl = value; }
        ....
    }
}
```

Archivo.cs

```
namespace ClassLibraryName
{
    public class Archivo
    {
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor vacio
        /// </summary>
        public Archivo()
        {
            Descripcion = "";
        }

        public Archivo(string clave) : this()
        {

            ....
            string Descripcion = ConfiguracionCMS.ClaveApartadoUrl ;
            ....
    }
}
}
```